# Nodejs streaming video files to response blocks after number of clients

Tags: node.js

I'm experimenting with ways to stream video file to browser client with `nodejs`. i got a working code that does the job and everything works great

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

app.get('/clips/:name',function(req,res){
    var file = path.resolve(__dirname,req.params.name);
    fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
      if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
          // 404 Error if file not found
          return res.sendStatus(404);
        }
      res.end(err);
      }
      var range = req.headers.range;
      if (!range) {
       // 416 Wrong range
       return res.sendStatus(416);
      }
      var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
      var start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
      var total = stats.size;
      var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
      var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;

      res.writeHead(206, {
        "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        "Content-Length": chunksize,
        "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
      });

      var stream = fs.createReadStream(file, { start: start, end: end })
        .on("open", function() {
          stream.pipe(res);
        }).on("error", function(err) {
          res.end(err);
        });
    });
});

app.listen(80);
```

The only problem with this code is when multiple client browser tabs are connected to the server it blocks the next requests until a stream from a previous request is ended.

Comment: Could you add what Node.js version you're seeing this behaviour on? I've been searching for 15 minutes and haven't found why it'd be blocking :/

Comment: i'm using version 4.4.5

Comment: I believe that most browsers will limit the number of concurrent connections to the same host. Try and see if it works better when you open the streams from different browsers.

Comment: YES, you are right with chrome alone the maximum of connections is always 6. so i used Firefox too and could go beyond 6 with no problem.